# Need to create custom navigation header for calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, antd

I have an Antd calendar I'm using as part of a larger React project. This component will load data from an API response and map a set of dates and times `AM, PM, ANY`, each with their own unique ID, to the dates on the calendar for a date/time selection like `07/12/2019` and `PM`

Out of the box, the default header styles for selecting a month and a year look like [this](https://ant.design/components/calendar/#components-calendar-demo-card).

I'm trying to change those to include a custom header that simply lists the month name and year (example:`July 2019`) and a left and right chevron for navigating between the months.

I've included the chevrons but when it comes to implementing the navigation functionality and how to render the name of the current month and year I'm completely at a loss.

I've included a CodeSandbox here to show my current progress

[image: Edit stoic-mcclintock-0dp6p]

`My Calendar Component`

```
import React from "react";
import { Calendar, Select, Radio, Col, Row } from "antd";
import { FaChevronRight, FaChevronLeft } from "react-icons/fa";
import styled from "styled-components";

const { Group, Button } = Radio;

function onPanelChange(value, mode) {
  console.log(value, mode);
}

const StylingCalendar = props => (
  <div style={{ width: 300, border: "1px solid #d9d9d9", borderRadius: 4 }}>
    <Calendar
      fullscreen={false}
      headerRender={({ value, type, onChange, onTypeChange }) => {
        const start = 0;
        const end = 12;
        const monthOptions = [];

        const current = value.clone();
        const localeData = value.localeData();
        const months = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
          current.month(i);
          months.push(localeData.monthsShort(current));
        }

        for (let index = start; index < end; index++) {
          monthOptions.push(
            <Select.Option className="month-item" key={`${index}`}>
              {months[index]}
            </Select.Option>
          );
        }
        const month = value.month();

        const year = value.year();
        const options = [];
        for (let i = year - 10; i < year + 10; i += 1) {
          options.push(
            <Select.Option key={i} value={i} className="year-item">
              {i}
            </Select.Option>
          );
        }
        return (
          <div style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <div style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}>{monthOptions.name}</div>
            <Row type="flex" justify="space-between">
              {/* <Col>
                <Group
                  size="small"
                  onChange={e => onTypeChange(e.target.value)}
                  value={type}
                >
                  <Button value="month">Month</Button>
                  <Button value="year">Year</Button>
                </Group>
              </Col> */}
              {/* <Col>
                <Select
                  size="small"
                  dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
                  className="my-year-select"
                  onChange={newYear => {
                    const now = value.clone().year(newYear);
                    onChange(now);
                  }}
                  value={String(year)}
                >
                  {options}
                </Select>
              </Col> */}
              <Col span={8}>
                <LeftArrow onClick={null} />
              </Col>
              <Col span={8}>
                {/* <FaChevronLeft /> */}
                <Select
                  size="small"
                  dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
                  value={String(month)}
                  onChange={selectedMonth => {
                    const newValue = value.clone();
                    newValue.month(parseInt(selectedMonth, 10));
                    onChange(newValue);
                  }}
                >
                  {monthOptions}
                </Select>
              </Col>
              <Col span={8}>
                <RightArrow onClick={null} />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
        );
      }}
      onPanelChange={onPanelChange}
    />
  </div>
);

const RightArrow = styled(FaChevronRight)`
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const LeftArrow = styled(FaChevronLeft)`
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export default StylingCalendar;
```

Comment: Your component is stateless how you intend to change the current month with a state? Try adding a current moment state

Comment: Moreover, you trying too hard, what is the purpose of this component? Are you trying to pick a date? or just present a calendar?

Comment: Part 1 of this is to display a calendar, Part 2 is to show the date selected along with a drop down menu to select a time of either ```AM, PM, ANY``` to the right of the calendar

Comment: So are you trying to schedule a date? Please try to add your component purpose in your question, because I think you overdo it and I can show you an easy workaround

Comment: Ah yeah essentially, I'm trying to schedule a date and a time but the overall component will load a JSON response from an API call and attach a set of 3 times: ```AM, PM, ANY``` each with their own unique ID to the set of dates in that response. The component purpose is a lot deeper than my question I was just trying to knock out the initial styling and navigation of the calendar first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`DatePicker`](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/) with `showTime` funcionallity, check the [example](https://3vyz0z018p.codesandbox.io/), by pressing on `select time`.

[image]

```js
<div>
  <DatePicker
    showTime
    placeholder="Select Time"
    onChange={onChange}
    onOk={onOk}
  />
</div>
```

[image: Edit 3vyz0z018p]

Moreover, if you use `open` property you get exactly the component you trying to implement:

```
<DatePicker open showTime placeholder="Select Time" />
```

Comment: This is so close, but now I've gotta figure out a way to display the open calendar on the left and the date selector input on the right as a separate component

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting the same problem. It's so easy if you using onChange prop of the Calendar Component.
Code of the button to change month like this:

```
`<Button
   onClick={() => {
      const newValue = moment(value).subtract(1, 'M')
      onChange(newValue)
   }
>
{'last month'}
</Button>`
```